# I want to show the json data from action in the datatable

Tags: asp.net, json, datatable

The table is empty. No data is coming.

```java
public JsonResult GetData(){
Uri url=new Uri("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums");
WebClient client=new WebClient();
client.Encoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string json=client.DownloadString(url);
return Json(json);
}
```

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>artist</th>
            <th>url</th>

         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
datatype:"json",
url:"/Home/GetData",
succes:function(data){
    var obj=Json.parse(data);
}
})
var table=$('#example').DataTable({
'data':obj,
'paging':true,
'searching':true,
'ordering':true
})
})
</script>
```

I can parse the JSON data into the list and write it to the table with the viewbag, but I have to JSON it to the datatable.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add columns in your bind operation, here is the code

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
     $.get("/Home/GetData", function(data, status){
     var obj=JSON.parse(data);
           var table=$('#example').DataTable({
        'data':obj,
        'paging':true,
        'searching':true,
        'ordering':true,
     "columns": [
        { data: "title" },
        { data: "artist" },
        { data: "url" }
        ]
        });
    });
  });
```

```html
 <!--Import jQuery before export.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


    <!--Data Table-->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

    <!--Export table buttons-->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>



<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>artist</th>
            <th>url</th>

         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```